# How to find unclosed Spring Data JPA streaming result set

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm using the streaming result sets provided by Spring Data JPA's repositories along with MySQL in order to reduce memory consumption of methods that involve scanning large results sets (which is looking increasingly like a hopelessly vain attempt; in theory the idea of using streams for this is brilliant; in practice, the constrainsts are very difficult to work with).

If I attempt to start using a second query in a thread while a stream produced by a previos query is unclosed, I get an exception like this:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not extract ResultSet

    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:982)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
...
Root cause: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not extract ResultSet
    org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:47)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:111)
    ...
java.sql.SQLException: Streaming result set com.mysql.jdbc.RowDataDynamic@15f2d1f is still active. No statements may be issued when any streaming result sets are open and in use on a given connection. Ensure that you have called .close() on any active streaming result sets before attempting more queries.
    com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:868)
    com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:864)
    com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkForOutstandingStreamingData(MysqlIO.java:3214)
...
```

Unfortunately, when I locate my code in the very long stack trace, when I look at it I don't see any items that are allocated and not disposed, so I'm not really sure what's going on.  How can I go about finding which query was not closed on time?

Comment: Based on the stacktrace you're using the same `Connection` to start a new query while the old one is still in use. How are you handling your connections?

Comment: @Kayaman Spring Data JPA handles the connection management.  I believe it uses one connection per transaction, and I'm using Spring's declarative transaction management to start a new transaction for each user request if one is required.

Comment: You're going to have to show some code. Somehow you're not finishing processing one query before starting another.

Comment: @Kayaman - yes, I'm aware of that.  But the code is very complex, there are many possible queries that could be at issue, and is considered by my customer to be commercially critical confidential information.  Which is why I'm asking if there are any useful techniques for finding the unclosed query.

Comment: Well, based on the information you're giving away, a debugger?